# Scraping a site with JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios

i am trying to scrape a web page, here is the JS code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const r = 704290;
const link = 'https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/';
const link_completo = link + r.toString();
const headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0',
  'Referer': 'http://www.discogs.com'
};

console.log(link_completo);

axios.get(link_completo, { headers })
  .then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    const artist = $('h1').text();

    console.log('Artist:', artist.trim());
  });
```

here is the HTML:

```html
<h1 class="title_1q3xW">
  <span class="link_15cpV">
    <a href="/artist/20991-The-Rolling-Stones" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor link_15cpV">The Rolling Stones</a>
  </span> – <!-- -->Black And Blue
</h1>
```

here is the output:

```txt
Artist: The Rolling Stones
                     ‎–
                                                     Black And Blue
```

when i change the line

```
const artist = $('h1').text();
```

to get accurately the Artist name (The Rolling Stones)

```
const artist = $('.title_1q3xW').text()
```

i get no response

same with:

```
const artist = $('.link_15cpV').text()
```

This is my first question in Stack Overflow, be patience please if the question can be silly. Thank you for patience

```js
const artist = $('.link_15cpV').text();
console.log(artist);
```

```html
<h1 class="title_1q3xW"><span class="link_15cpV">
<a href="/artist/20991-The-Rolling-Stones" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor link_15cpV">The Rolling Stones</a></span> –
  <!-- -->Black And Blue</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: The demo above seems to work, but keep in mind that a jQuery class selector returns _all_ elements with that class, and chained methods iterate over each of them. You see the text twice because there are two elements with that class.

Comment: I am not seeing any of those classes on the elements when I load it in the browser directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is `The Rolling Stones` that is located in the `a` tag.

Something like:

`$('h1 a').text();`

might work. Here's how it works in JavaScript in the browser.

```js
document.getElementById('artist-name').innerText = document.querySelector('h1 a').text;
```

```html
<h1 class="title_1q3xW"><span class="link_15cpV">
<a href="/artist/20991-The-Rolling-Stones" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor link_15cpV">The Rolling Stones</a></span> –
  <!-- -->Black And Blue</h1>

<h2>Inserting Artist Name Below<h2>
<h2 id="artist-name"></h2>
```